# Bash Script - Daemon

Tags: bash, shell

I'm not a programmer, nor a security expert. I work with CheckPoint and I have the following code, developed by me for use with CheckPoint Logs management:

```
#!/bin/bash -

# Necessario carregar as variaveis do CheckPoint:
. /etc/profile.d/CP.sh

# Description:
# Log management

# Crontab:
#0 */1 * * * nohup /etc/scripts/log start 0<&- 1>> /var/log/LOG 2>&1 &

# Vars:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/etc/scripts
FILE=/var/log/LOG
SLEEP=600
RUN_TIME=01
LOG_DIR=$FWDIR/log
GZIP_RET=1
SCP_RET=1
SCP_USR=openssh
SCP_DEST_DIR=LOGS_RJ
SCP_IP=192.168.1.41
TIME=$(clock | awk {'print $4'} | cut -d ':' -f 1)
CHECK=$(ps aux | grep 'log start' | grep -v grep | wc -l)
DATE=$(date +%y%m%d)

# Functions:

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [start|stop]" >&2
    exit 1
}

do_launch() {
    if [ "$CHECK" -eq 2 ] ; then
        set -x
        #exec >> /var/log/LOG 2>&1
    else
        exit
    fi
}

do_compression() {
    SEARCH=`find "$LOG_DIR" -name '20*' -daystart -follow -mtime +$GZIP_RET | grep -v gz`
    for i in $SEARCH ; do
        gzip -f -9 $i ;
    done
}

do_scp() {
    SEARCH=`find "$LOG_DIR" -name '20*' -daystart -follow -mtime +$SCP_RET`
    for i in $SEARCH ; do
        scp $i $SCP_USR@$SCP_IP:$SCP_DEST_DIR && rm $i || break 1;
    done
}

# Work
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]
then
    usage
else
    case "$@" in
        start)
            while true ; do
                do_launch
                while true ; do
                    if [ "$TIME" -eq "$RUN_TIME" ] ; then
                        do_scp
                    else
                        do_compression
                    fi
                    sleep $SLEEP
                done
            done
            ;;
        stop)
            pkill -x log
            ;;
        *)
        usage
    esac
fi

exit
```

The script runs fine when run manually, but when I put in crontab `nohup /etc/scripts/log start 0<&- 1>> /var/log/LOG 2>&1 &` or even run from terminal and logout and login, the script fail to loop/run but it is still runnning from `ps`.

Can someone help me?

Also, the bash version is 2.05b from CheckPoint, but if everything is fine from manual, I don't think the version is the reason.

Comment: By manual mode you mean you are running `/etc/scripts/log start 0<&- 1>> /var/log/LOG 2>&1` from the terminal and is running then it should work with `nohup` as well. How do you conclude it's *not working*?

Comment: I conclude that is not running because i can't see the LOG increasing nor the log compress etc finishing the job. Thanks for the answer !!!

Comment: See @jonathan's asnwer below. Once you fix those issues, the script could work. Though I am suspicious your claim that it's working from terminal..

Answer (score 2):

Given that the top of the file lists:

```
SLEEP=600
RUN_TIME=01
...
TIME=$(clock | awk {'print $4'} | cut -d ':' -f 1)
```

This is a bit surprising:

```
if [ "$TIME" -eq "$RUN_TIME" ] ; then
```

Nothing changes those values, so either you're lucky and the output from `clock` (not a command I'm familiar with) matches the `01` or it doesn't.  If it matches, then the loop will do the `do_scp` action; otherwise, it will do the `do_compression` action.  However, once launched, I see nothing that will make it ever do the other action.

To fix, you probably need to evaluate TIME on each iteration.  You also need to consider whether the method chosen for handling the switch between the two actions is appropriate; I think it is dubious.

Comment: I am guessing he mistakenly used `clock` instead of `date`. But it's surprising he claims it's working when run from the terminal.

Comment: Clock is a CheckPoint command. Thanks for the answer, i am sure you are right ! That's nothing increasing or checking the $TIME ... i checked the log and now i can see it repeats "if 15 = 01" ... so it's no increasing really. Many thanks.

Comment: @KingsIndian Thanks for the observation. Actually "clock" is the same as "date" LOL, the same output etc etc. Just for CheckPoint reasons, they renamed the command. Thanks !

Comment: You guys are really amazing ! Thanks ... my problem is solved ! Jonathan, your answer is right. Thanks for all of you.